# Rename the file if exists instead of overwriting it

Tags: java

When I execute below code it overwrite the existing file. I want to keep old file and new file too. What can be done here? Can we rename it like Test(1).xlsx, Test(2).xlsx, Test(3).xlsx like windows pattern?

```
File excel = new File("C:\\TEST\\Test.xlsx");
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel); 
     XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);) {
    ..
    ..
    ..
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\TEST\\Output\\Test.xlsx")) {
        book.write(outputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, you need create a file before write, save it and later write. I trying remember if that library have something for do that automatically, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file already exists using the `exists()` method before you start writing to it.
If the file already exists, write to a different file.

```
File excel = new File(determineFileName());
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
     XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);) {
...
}
```

with

```
private String determineFileName(){
  String path = "C:\\TEST\\Test.xlsx";
  int counter = 0;
  while(new File(path).exists()){
    counter++;
    path = "C:\\TEST\\Test(" + counter + ").xlsx";
  }
  return path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Implemented in this way and it is working as expected.